# Collision of two light rays from the viewpoint of a moving observer

Tags: special-relativity

Two light rays in the $(x,y)$ plane of an inertial observer F, making angles $\theta$ and $-\theta$, respectively, with the positive $x$ axis, collide at the origin. What is the velocity $v$ of the inertial observer $F'$ (in standard configuration) who sees the light rays collide head on? I initially thought it has to be $-c$, but it seems I have misunderstood the question.

Edit: Is the following correct? using conservation of 4-momentum, we have $p_1+p_2=p_3$ with $p_1=(h\nu,h\nu cos\theta,h\nu sin\theta,0),p_2=(h\nu,h\nu cos\theta,-h\nu sin\theta,0), p_3=m\gamma(u)(1,u,0,0)$.Equating components, we have $2h\nu=m\gamma(u)\implies m=\frac{2h\nu}{\gamma(u)}$ and $2h\nu cos\theta=-m\gamma(u)u=-\frac{2h\nu}{\gamma(u)}\gamma(u)u\implies u=-ccos\theta$